# Is the following sequence bounded below by zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The sequence $s_1=3$ and $s_{k+1}=\sqrt{3s_k-1}$, where $k$ is a natural number. My guess is that this is bounded below by zero. Is this correct? 
what is it bounded by?

--

(*Edit @Did: Here is the modified version which replaced the original version above, after two answers addressing it were posted.*)

The sequence $s_1=2$ and $s_{k+1}=\sqrt{2s_k+1}$, where $k$ is a natural number. My guess is that this is bounded below by zero. Is this correct? 
what is it bounded by?

Comment: If always defined, it *is* bounded by zero – it's part of the definition of $\sqrt x$.

Comment: The only thing that can affect whether it's defined is if what under the root is positive, so you have to show that $3s_k-1$ is always postive.

Comment: OP: You replaced "$s_1=3$ and $s_{k+1}=\sqrt{3s_k-1}$" by "$s_1=2$ and $s_{k+1}=\sqrt{2s_k+1}$" after two answers were posted. What is this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that
$$s_k \le 3 \Rightarrow s_{k+1} \le \sqrt{3\cdot 3 - 1} = \sqrt 8 < 3$$
and
$$s_k \ge 2 \Rightarrow s_{k+1} \ge \sqrt{3\cdot 2 - 1} = \sqrt{5} > 2$$
so $\{s_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is always defined and bounded by $[2,3]$ above and below resp. so it's especially bounded below by anything smaller than $2$, including $0$.
**Bonus**: To find the limit $s$, note that it must satisfy
$$2\le s\le 3 \text{ and } s = \sqrt{3s - 1}$$
Now you can show that with $s_1 \ge s$, $\{s_k\}$ is a nonincreasing sequence, so $s$ is not only the limit but also the best lower bound for $\{s_k\}$

Comment: @Maury Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is defined (as in 'makes sense') only for nonnegative real numbers, so that the iteration $s_{k+1} = \sqrt{3s_k - 1}$ only is defined ('makes sense') if the thing under the $\sqrt\cdot$ is nonnegative, i.e. if $3s_k-1\ge 0$. This is only the case if $s_k \ge \frac13$ for all $k$. But since $s_k \ge 2\ge \frac13$, we have proven that $s_k$ is allways defined (so you don't hit a wall somewhere when actually evaluating the expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $s_k\geqslant2$ then $s_{k+1}\geqslant2$. (Thus, for every $s_1\geqslant2$, the sequence $(s_k)$ is well defined.)

**Edit:** The question was modified (which it ought not have been) and now asks "what is [the sequence starting from $s_1=3$] bounded below by?" To that, the optimal answer is: $\frac12(3+\sqrt5)$. And the picture that says it all:

[image]

Comment: I didn't modify the question..Im still asking the same thing

Comment: @Maury Your change in words now implies search for the best lower bound (wich is not $0$).

Comment: ok sorry I did not mean to say that

Comment: Interesting downvotes--purely for mathematical reasons, to be sure.

Comment: @DanielFisher You prefer the lame "which it ought not have been" to the playful "shame on the OP"? [I disagree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEzQV75LDL0). The good news is that, if a mod has time for such edits, this can only mean that the site is going VERY well.

Comment: I prefer whatever does not cause others to flag. ('Cause, you know, flags = work for us.) By the way, you forgot the 'c' in my name, thus I wasn't pinged.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for the missing 'c'. The supplementary work is unfortunate, yes, but we might want to recognize that, in some cases, flags are just stupid.

Comment: Yes, but between the just stupid flags, and the obviously good ones, there's room for those where we flip a coin.